# How to check in f# if the set is Empty?

Tags: f#, is-empty

How can I check if the set is empty, I have implemented the following code if the set has an empty set then I should get the value true else false, for example: [1; 2; []] this set should result in true and if the set is [1; 2; 3] this should result in false because this one does not have an empty set in it. Following is the code that gives me an error:

```
let rec isEmpty S =
   match S with
  |[] -> true
  |_ -> false
  |e::rest -> ([]=e) || (isEmpty [] rest)
```

Comment: Your match will never reach the third case, because the `_` case matches *everything*. So any non-empty list will match against `_` and return `false`, and the `e::rest` case will never be checked. (Robert Nielsen has already pointed out another problem, which is that F# doesn't allow mixed lists: a list containing integers cannot also contain lists.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately for your use case F# is quite a bit more 'strongly typed' than you would like here.

In F# a value like [1; 2; 3] is an int list, and an int list won't accept a value like [1; 2; []].

Maybe you could try to define a new (recursive) datatype for your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comment.  Since f# auto detects the data type, I was in an impression that by default the auto detect will also detect the empty set as an int or some kind of data type base on its powerful auto-detection mechanism. You have clarified that this is not the case and I appreciate your time and response.